# CCD camera honeycomb pattern (noise removal)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, noise-reduction

I have been doing some image processing on images of lasers taken from a GrayScale DataRay WinCamD ccd camera and have noticed a weird honeycomb effect in the background. I've attached images of the effect (I enhanced the effect using GIMP to make it more visable and it also has a jet colormap) What causes that pattern?

[image]

I am trying to remove that noise and I am thinking of just getting a section of the back ground such as the topright corner and subtracting the average pixel value of that section from the entire image (baseline subtraction). But are there any better methods for the task?

I am using openCV as well but I am afraid to use too many filters or too much thresholding because I could remove some vital data from the image.

I am trying to follow the ISO 11146-1 Standard for my measurements. Documentation on that standard can be found [here](http://www.auniontech.com/uploadfile/2011/35/13149580538536.pdf) (PDF).

Comment: is it really grayscale or maybe bayer pattern for example? what's the color of your laser? can you try different lighting?

Comment: It's from this [camera](http://www.dataray.com/wincamd-ucd15-beam-profiling-camera.html) And the color of the laser is within the infrared spectrum. As for lighting the camera is placed in an enclosure to minimize any ambient lighting.

Comment: maybe it works similar to bayern pattern so that there is some kind of "mask" on the sensor and every second pixel in each row cant capture that qave length? of your laser? That's why you should try to capture different scenes to test whether that "noise" occurs on all kind of input wave lengths

Comment: Sorry for the late response (busy with the holidays), I think you are correct with your assumption because at higher light intensities the pattern is still there. If I can I'll try with a different beam type. Thanks for the advice!